# Telerik RadSplitContainer SizeInfo RelativeRatio

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, telerik, splitpanel

According to the Telerik docs, the relative size of the panels in a RadSplitContainer are set with the RelativeRatio property.  I can't figure out how to use this property.

I would like a left panel and a right panel, the left panel 50% of the width of the right panel.

http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/splitcontainer-overview.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy:

- Set both panels inside the splitcontainer to relative
- Then set the RelativeRatio of the right panel = 0.66, 0 and the
  RelativeRatio of the left panel = 0.33,0:

### Example:

[image]

EDIT :

[image]

EDIT 2:

```
        splitPanel1.SizeInfo.SizeMode = Telerik.WinControls.UI.Docking.SplitPanelSizeMode.Relative;
        splitPanel2.SizeInfo.SizeMode = Telerik.WinControls.UI.Docking.SplitPanelSizeMode.Relative;

        splitPanel1.SizeInfo.RelativeRatio = new SizeF(0.33f, 0f);
        splitPanel2.SizeInfo.RelativeRatio = new SizeF(0.66f, 0f);
```

Comment: to precisely which object does the property RelativeRatio belong? And how do you assign the RelativeRatio property? It expects an object whose type is `SizeF`.

Comment: @Tim Click on both split panels to access their respective RelativeRatio. See my editted screenshot for where it is.

Comment: I added the controls at runtime, not in the designer.

Comment: @Tim IF you're making them at runtime, you will have their name's. Use Edit2 in my post.